# Hashmap and arraylist add items to top

Tags: android

I am using `linkedHashMap` and `ArrayList` when user preses a button i am adding new data to `linkedHashMap` and `ArrayList` like this:

```
conversationsMap.put(currentTime,userStringData);
conversationsList=new ArrayList<Conversation>(conversationsMap.values());
```

Then I am showing the list to user via an adapter.

My problem starts here.This code is adding last item to bottom.I don't want this.I want to add last item to top of the list.

What is the best way to achive this ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simple solution to your problem:

```
conversationsList=new ArrayList<Conversation>(Collections.reverse(conversationsMap.values()));
```

**Update:** If you are looking for a way to insert values into a ListView at specific locations you might want to use the [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) instead, which offers the `insert(T object, int index)` method.

Comment: Actually I know this solution but i am not sure is this the best way

Comment: Why did you not include it in your problem description, then?